# How to create a list of strings based on enum type items in c#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum type like this:

```
public enum Colors
    {
        Black,
        Brown,
        Red,
        Orange,
        Yellow,
        Green,
        Blue,
        Violet,
        Grey,
        White
    }
```

And I want to create an array of strings based on items in this enum type. Like this:

```
strint[] mylist = {"Black", "Brown", "Red", ... }
```

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: the method Enum.GetNames does just that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy, since the `Enum` class provides [a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=net-7.0) for that:

```
string[] mylist = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors));
```